# Qt translations loaded after window load

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to setup translations for a qt app but it seems that the translations files are loaded after the window because the only translated text are the ones in messages box

This is the code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTranslator>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("Lebbadi");
    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationDomain("lebbadi.fr");
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("zNavigo");

    QTranslator translator;

    if(translator.load(QLocale(QLocale::French), "app", "_", ":/translations"))
        app.installTranslator(&translator);
    else
        exit(-1);

    MainWindow window;
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I didn't get your question?

Comment: To which messageBox do you mean?, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently your question falls on the off-topic: ***why isn't this code working?** must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers* , so I think it should be closed, for more information read the following: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Can you show us the code of the (not translated) MainWindow and the (translated) messages boxes?
Or as @eyllanesc says, a MCVE?

Comment: https://www.github.com/RomainL972/zNavigo the about section is translated